# We use Dropbox at work but files saved by one user don't show up for another

Tags: dropbox

We have one Dropbox for storing files at work.  Some of us use Windows Office 2007, some 2010.  When files are saved by one user they don't show up on other users Dropbox.  Please keep answers suitable for a non-techy numpty type, thanks

Comment: please clarify if they all use the same account or different accounts; If different, specify if they have shared the folders with one another?

Comment: We have one account and share folders within the same dropbox.

Comment: Check the sync setting of these folders on each user's machine. If the user's are using selective sync, only those folders will be synced/updated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everyone has their Dropbox Account and has not shared any folder.
To share a Common folder among users. Just create a *New Shared Folder* and Invite other users with whom you want to share this folder.
Or if you want to share an existing folder `Right Click > Share This Folder` and enter the email addresses of the people you want to invite.

A more detailed guide can be found here:  [How do I share folders with other people?](https://www.dropbox.com/help/19/en)

Comment: We have dropbox installed on our computers, we don't go to dropbox.com to share folders.  When one person updates a document or saves a new one on their computer, we should all be able to pick it up on our own but this isn't happening with all documents.